# Hiding/Unhiding group of GUI Text in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have created a empty GameObject to contain GUI Text objects, how can I make them hidden? Will I use the renderer or will I just one by one pick those GUI Text objects and set its active to false? I don't want the long part that's why I was just wondering how'll I do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to just activate and deactivate the game object that holds all the GUI Text objects.